# For-Comprehension Example with \/ and IO

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given the following `Foo` case class:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int)
defined class Foo
```

I check if it's a valid `Foo` before constructing it inside of `validateFoo`:

```
scala> def validateFoo(foo: Foo): \/[String, Foo] = 
              (if(foo.x > 0) foo.success[String] 
              else ("invalid foo").failure[Foo]).disjunction
validateFoo: (foo: Foo)scalaz.\/[String,Foo]
```

Lastly, `f` creates a `Foo`, and then tries to perform an `IO` action (example: save `Foo` to database).

```
scala> def f(x: Foo): IO[\/[String,Int]] = for {
     |    foo <- validateFoo(x)
     |    ioFoo <- IO { foo }
     | } yield ioFoo
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.effect.IO[Foo]
 required: scalaz.\/[?,?]
          ioFoo <- IO { foo }
                ^
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.\/[String,Nothing]
 required: scalaz.effect.IO[scalaz.\/[String,Int]]
          foo <- validateFoo(x)
              ^
```

However, I ran into the above issue when trying to chain the `bind`'s together in the for-comprehension.

The problem, as I see it, is that the proper return type is `IO[\/[String, Int]]`. However, I don't know how to validate `Foo` **and** handle it in the `IO` monad with a for-comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't combine `String \/ A` and `IO[A]` computations like this—if you desugared your `for`-comprehension you'd see that the types just don't work out.

If you really wanted to, you could use a monad transformer to compose the two monads. Suppose we have the following setup, for example (which is essentially your code, but cleaned up a bit, and with a new method representing the database operation):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._

case class Foo(x: Int)

def validateFoo(foo: Foo): String \/ Foo =
  (foo.x > 0) either foo or "invalid foo"

def processFoo(foo: Foo): IO[Foo] = IO {
  println(foo)
  foo
}
```

Now we can write the following:

```
type IOStringOr[A] = EitherT[IO, String, A]

def f(x: Foo): IOStringOr[Foo] = for {
  foo <- EitherT(validateFoo(x).point[IO])
  ioFoo <- processFoo(foo).liftIO[IOStringOr]
} yield ioFoo
```

Now you can run the `EitherT` to get an `IO` action:

```
val ioAction: IO[String \/ Foo] = f(Foo(10)).run
```

That's how you *could* use `\/` and `IO` together in a `for`-comprehension. It's pretty definitely overkill in your case, though. I'd probably write something like this:

```
def f(x: Foo): IO[String \/ Foo] =
  validateFoo(x).bitraverse(_.point[IO], processFoo)
```

This uses the `Bitraverse` instance for `\/` to map a function into `IO` over both sides of the disjunction and then turn the whole thing inside out.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have an error in your definition of validateFoo. I think you want

```
scala> def validateFoo(foo: Foo): \/[String, Foo] = 
          (if(foo.x > 0) foo.success[Foo] 
          else ("invalid foo").failure[String]).disjunction
```

You've mixed up the String and Foo in the success and failure cases.

Comment: The original version was correct. `foo.success[String]` returns a `Validation[String, Foo]`, etc.

Comment: @rgcase, I asked this question (which parameters to use) on the [scalaz mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/M7JjIkMBwaY)